# I am running a simple mediation model. How do I control for race, and if I do, will I loose statistical power?

Tags: mediation, confounding, path-model, mplus

I am running a simple mediation model in a path analysis framework using Mplus.

[image]

The direct path in my model is grades (independent variable) predicting happiness (dependent variable). The indirect path is grades predicting happiness through self-esteem. All variables are continuous.
There are 3 racial groups in my dataset: White, Black, and Latino. If I wanted to control for race, how would I do that? Would I just run 1 model with all the White participants, and 1 model with all the Black participants? And if I stratify the groups by race (assuming this is how I control for variables), does that mean I have less statistical power in each model?

Comment: How do you think race should interact in your causal diagram with the other variables?

Comment: The research corpus suggests a moderate correlation between the independent and dependent variables with race.

Comment: What you need to do before answering your question, is to put race as another node in your diagram, and fill in the arrows you think should be there, ESPECIALLY including direction of the arrows. There are possibly other ways to condition for race - if you need to. You won't know if you need to unless you can put it as another node and show its relation to the other nodes.